# Difference between concentration and attention

Tags: attention, concentration

Is there any difference between concentration and attention ?

The dictionary definition and some websites on psychology mention they are same. whereas many people say they are different. I am unable to figure it out

Comment: Can you cite examples of where they are claimed to be the same or different? Both can be true, language isn't ever that strict.